# I think one of my comments went missing, is it in a better place now?

Tags: support

I'm sure that I posted a comment [to this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62245/when-and-why-is-it-necessary-for-the-subject-to-look-in-the-camera).

This comment is nowhere to be found now.
At first I thought I simply forgot to submit it.
But being asked why I deleted the comment makes me somewhat confident that I did in fact post it.

I don't think I deleted that comment.
Is there a way to see deleted comments on my profile page? I don't think so.

Or was that comment deleted? It wasn't an answer, but that's why I posted it as a comment. Maybe somebody flagged it because it could be considered somewhat off topic.

I'm not sure if one receives a notification when a comment is deleted. That'S why I'm confused.

I want to make it clear that I do not want to complain about the comment being deleted (if that's the case) and don't even need to know the reason either. I just want to know if I somehow deleted it by accident or if it was deleted by someone else. Sometimes I'm a bit clumsy.

Comment: The comment was deleted by a moderator. Unfortunately, comment moderation leaves no artifact - no revision history or annotation - so I cannot speak to why it was deleted; I'll leave that for the moderator to explain if they wish.

Comment: @abbyhairboat thanks, that's all I wanted to know.

Comment: The comment was flagged as not constructive by another user. This can often happen when a comment is perceived to be overly critical. On second reading, I think the flagging person misread. I can bring it back since the OP indicates they're okay with it. Also, before you ask, I removed the comments asking about it. :)

Comment: Of course, now the comment doesn't make sense since the image was edited out of the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confess — I flagged it! Not because I thought it was overly critical (I would have gone for the "rude or offensive" flag in that case), but because I thought was basically off-topic, and therefore not constructive to the discussion at hand.

I think comments on questions should generally relate to the question being asked, or at least the problem the asker needs resolved. And, they should mostly be assumed to be transient — they should be used to improve the questions or answers and then removed, resulting in a cleaner "knowledge base" eventually. The main exception would be short comments pointing to other questions or answers on the site. (And based on the culture of the site here, the other exception is probably short jokes.)

Basically, if we use the comments section for open-ended critique or photo-assistance, that could really get out of control.

If we  *do* want to leave comments like this instead, especially on questions which are about a particular photograph, I guess I could be convinced. :)

Comment: I agree. I wasn't sure either but felt like, "oh well, it's just a comment, it will cause no harm". There are a lot of off-topic or funny comments to be found on other SE sites, which encouraged me to post mine because it as it isn't entirely unrelated.

Comment: For cases where site members feel like an image deserves further discussion, one idea might be to create a new chat room (bottom of page at http://chat.stackexchange.com/). This will stay open as long as it has activity (14 day timeout), and be retained forever even when closed if there are at least 15 messages and two participants. Then, _that_ could be linked in a short comment.